# password confirmation in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to check whether the two passwords are equal. I am not getting any error message when there are not but i am not getting the error message **"Password must match"**.

Below is my DOM:

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': formName.get('password').touched && 
                formName.get('password').hasError('invalidPassword')}">
    <label class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="password" name="password" required />
</div>

<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': formName.get('confirmpassword').touched 
        && formName.get('confirmpassword').hasError('mismatchedPasswords')}">
    <label class="control-label">confirm password</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" required />
    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="formName.get('confirmpassword').touched 
            && formName.get('confirmpassword').hasError('mismatchedPasswords')">
            Password must match
        </span>
</div>
```

My Component class on how i am building my form:

```
   this.formName = this.fb.group({
        name: ["", [Validators.required]],            
        password: ["",[Validators.required, ValidationHelper.passwordValidator]],
        confirmpassword: ["",Validators.required],
        info: this.fb.group({
            acc: ["",[Validators.required, ValidationHelper.creditCardValidator]]
        })
   },{ validator: ValidationHelper.matchPass})
```

And my password matching function:

```
static matchPass = (control: AbstractControl) : {[key: string]: boolean} => {    
    let password = control.get('password');
    let confirmPassword = control.get('confirmpassword');
    return password.value === confirmPassword.value ? null : { 'mismatchedPasswords': true };        
}
```

The function is getting called, i am also getting the return value... but why is my confirm password input control not showing error or activitating its span tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with these lines in your template:

`formName.get('confirmpassword').hasError('mismatchedPasswords')`

You're applying the validator to the group `formName`, but checking for the error on the `confirmpassword` formControl.

Try using this in the two places where you check for `mismatchedPasswords` in your template.

`formName.hasError('mismatchedPasswords')`