# How to validate passwords for new and confirm password in angular2

Tags: angular

I have 2 fields, password and confirm password.
So, how do i validate both?
HTML:

```
<div class="mb-4  col-lg-6">
              <label >Password
                <span class="required">*</span>
              </label>
              <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password"
formControlName="Password">
              <control-messages [control]="controls.Password" class="errorMessage"></control-messages>
              <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="validationPassBlank==1">{{errorMessage}}</div>
             <div class='required' *ngIf="validationError == 1">{{errorMessage}}</div>
            </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258947/password-confirmation-in-angular-2?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to be using [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

You need to Create one more `field` for `Confirm Password`, and give different name as ConfirmPassword

In the `FormGroup` declare one more field as "ConfirmPassword" and give.

```
ConfirmPassword: [''] ,{ validator: [ValidationService.matchingConfirmPasswords] }
```

**Add function to check passwords**,

```
static matchingConfirmPasswords(passwordKey: any) { 
    let passwordInput = passwordKey['value']; 
    if (passwordInput.Password === passwordInput.ConfirmPassword) { 
        return null; 
    } 
    else { 
        return passwordKey.controls['ConfirmPassword'].setErrors({ passwordNotEquivalent: true }); 
    } 
}
```

**In your html:**

```
<div class="mb-4 col-lg-6"> 
    <label > Confirm Password 
        <span class="required">*</span> 
    </label> 
    <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder=" Confirm Password" 
    formControlName="Password"> 
    <control-messages [control]="registerForm.controls.ConfirmPassword" class="errorMessage"></control-messages> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Do something like this.

```
private buildForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      password: [null, Validators.required],
      repeat: [null, Validators.required]
    }, {validator: this.checkIfMatchingPasswords('password', 'repeat')});
}


private checkIfMatchingPasswords(passwordKey: string, passwordConfirmationKey: string) {
    return (group: FormGroup) => {
      const passwordInput = group.controls[passwordKey],
        passwordConfirmationInput = group.controls[passwordConfirmationKey];
      if (passwordInput.value !== passwordConfirmationInput.value) {
        return passwordConfirmationInput.setErrors({notEquivalent: true});
      } else {
        return passwordConfirmationInput.setErrors(null);
      }
    };
  }
```

And in the template inside the form.

```
<p *ngIf="form.get('repeat')?.errors?.notEquivalent">Passwords did not match</p>
<p *ngIf="form.get('repeat')?.errors?.required">Confirm password is required</p>
```

Comment: I am getting error as 

 Argument of type '{ validators: (group: FormGroup) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn | AbstractControlOptions | ValidatorFn[]'.
  Type '{ validators: (group: FormGroup) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
    Type '{ validators: (group: FormGroup) => void; }' provides no match for the signature '(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors'.

in angular 7